# Trying to query using PostgreSQL in R- ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer

Tags: r, postgresql

I am using the `PostgreSQL` package to query a database via `R`. I want to pull all the columns from a data table, `cond`, where the column `id` is an observation ID key, and the vector `of_interest`is a subset of observation IDs I would like to have the information for. The `of_interest` vector in R looks something like this:

```
of_interest <- c(1:5)
```

I write a query and then execute it like this:

```
query = paste('SELECT *
              FROM cond 
              WHERE id IN (',paste(of_interest,collapse=','),')')

COND = as.data.table(db.query(query, con=fia.con))
```

I then receive the following error:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 4:               WHERE id IN ( 1,2,3,4,5 )
                               ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any idea what may be wrong here? In the past I could easily query based on ID by structuring the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM cond
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Here are the results of `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_0.8-16     raster_2.2-31    sp_1.0-15        car_2.0-19       bit64_0.9-5      bit_1.1-12       RPostgreSQL_0.4  DBI_0.3.1        data.table_1.9.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] MASS_7.3-35     chron_2.3-45    grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29 nnet_7.3-8      tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: I've tried your problem with R package **RPostgreSQL** and it works correctly. But I am having issues to find package PostgreSQL64 that you mentioned.  Can you point a link to that package?

Comment: @grubjesic sorry, that was a typo. I was looking at my packages and the `RPostgreSQL` and `bit64` packages are loaded right next together. I must have mashed the names together by accident.

Comment: @grubjesic are you feeding the query the list `of_interest` as a converted R vector, rather than directly entering `(1,2,3,4,5)`?

Comment: Your `id` column is `character varying` instead of some numerical type but you query it with `int`s. PostgreSQL won't do any automatic type conversion for you (at least not for completely different types).

Comment: @pozs can you clarify `character varying`? Do you mean it contains both numeric and character entries? or that it is a character vector? This is surprising to me, as when I output the query as a data.table in R its definitely numeric.

Comment: @colin the error message you showed means the `id` column has `character varying` type, not numeric. You can double check that with [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) (`\d` option; command line tool) or with pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my example that works:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

Configuration.db.host.local <- "localhost"
Configuration.db.user.local <- "postgres"
Configuration.db.password.local <- "your password"
Configuration.db.dbname.local <- "your dbname"

local_con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), host=Configuration.db.host.local, user= Configuration.db.user.local,password=Configuration.db.password.local, dbname=Configuration.db.dbname.local)

of_interest <- c(1:5)
query = paste('SELECT *
              FROM cond 
              WHERE id IN (',paste(of_interest,collapse=','),')')

data <- dbGetQuery(local_con, query)
```

**Update:**

It seems your filed is string. In this case try to use this piece of code:

```
expr = paste0("('",paste(of_interest, collapse="','"),"')")
query = paste("SELECT *
              FROM cond 
              WHERE id IN ", expr)
```

Comment: this is strange to me! I'm still getting a similar error: `Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
LINE 3:               WHERE plt_cn IN ( 2222999010690, 2223994010690...
                                   ^`

Comment: added to question above

Comment: what's the type of field id or plt_cn  in the PostgresDB ?

Comment: as far as I can tell its numeric (when I grab it from the database and manipulate it in R later its definitely a numeric vector). how can I check this?

Comment: the problem was that the id was stored within the database as a character, rather than numeric. I had to modify the statement to: `WHERE plt_cn IN (',paste(shQuote(test, type="cmd"), collapse=", "),')'`